# c++ add string from .txt file into string array and display the value of the array

Tags: c++, fstream

I have a file containing the following: `tdogicatzhpigu` and another file containing the following:

```
dog
pig
cat
rat
fox
cow
```

on separate lines.

The following code shows my attempts to do this inside a menu which is a do while loop.

```
if (selection == 1) {

        //Gets the characters from the textfile and creates an array of characters.
        fstream fin1("text1.txt", fstream::in);
        if (fin1.is_open())
        {
            cout << "text1.txt successfully added to an array" << endl;
            while (!fin1.eof()) {
                if (!fin1.eof()) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 14; i++) {
                        for (int e = 0; e < 14; e++) {
                            fin1 >> chArray[i][e];

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else if (!fin1.is_open())
        {
            cout << "ERROR: ";
            cout << "Can't open text1.txt file\n";
        }
        fin1.close();
        //Get the string values from the file and add into an array of strings

        fstream fin2("search1.txt", fstream::in);
        if (fin2.is_open()) {
            cout << "Search1.txt successfully added to an array" << endl;
            cout << "------------------------------------------------------------------------" << endl;
            while (!fin2.eof()) {
                if (!fin2.eof()) {
                    for (int j = 0; j <= 6; ++j) {
                        getline(fin2, wordsArray[j]);

                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

now if I print the arrays within selection 1, it displays correctly for both, all is well, however in the following selection 2 I am trying to once again display the contents of  chArray but it misses the `"t"` out for some reason
:

```
else if (selection == 2) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 14; i++) {
            cout << chArray[0][i] << endl;
        }
```

With selection 3, trying to display the wordsArray, nothing displays at all, here is the code for selection 3:

```
else if (selection == 3) {
        for (int j = 0; j <= 6; ++j) {
            cout << wordsArray[j] << endl;
        }
```

Comment: I couldn't duplicate the problem, it works fine when i run it with the given input. BTW why are you using two dimensional array to store the characters?

Comment: And where in your program are you declaring the arrays?

Comment: the arrays are being declared outside of the do while loop, i would prefer to store each character into each element in the array but i am not sure how to get that working correctly, as in the file, it is together as one string, no spaces in-between the characters

Comment: Can you show the code that declares the arrays?

Comment: I forgot to mention the array containing the characters is a string array, so I'm trying to put each character into each element as a string, string chArray[14] and string wordsArray[6], just before do

Comment: how does the program run correctly in the first place. **fin1 >> chArray[i][e];** in your code is trying to access and write to a non existing location in the individual strings when you are assigning a value to it and when e>=1

Comment: What would you suggest replacing that with? I originally had it working fine with a character array but had to change it so a string array but need to put each character into each element

Comment: It would be better if you edit your question to include all the necessary declarations in your code relevant to the question. If the problem you are having can't be reproduced then it would be difficult to find a solution. When declaring **chArray** as an array of string and use your code in the question, the program will terminate(crash) because of illegal access of memory location and that is not the same problem as what you mentioned in your question.

Comment: That's strange that doesn't happen in my build it runs and builds no issue but just has the two issues I have put in the question

Comment: Literally just got the code shown there, and two string arrays declared outside the do while, and I get those two issues

Answer (score 2):

Try this(I have only written the changes you should make, so keep the other code as it is):

```
string chArray;
string wordsArray[6];

do
{
....//other code

if (selection == 1)
{

   if (fin1.is_open())
   {
      cout << "text1.txt successfully added to an array" << endl;
      if(!getline(fin1,chArray))//read the whole line from the file into the string
         //show error message that a file was not read successfully
   }

   .....

   for (int j = 0; j < 6; ++j)//change j<=6 to j<6 since your array has 6 elements

   .....

}
else if (selection == 2)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 14; i++)
       cout << chArray[i] << endl;//no need to access this as two dimensional array

.....

}
else if (selection == 3) 
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 6; ++j)//change j<=6 to j<6 since your array has 6 elements
      ....
}

}while(selection != your exit value);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I appreciate the help, I will implement the changes and let you know how it goes